# Strange autocompletion behavior in bash (Linux) using PATH variable with special symbol - apostroph (')

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, bash-completion

Well...I'm so confused, cause the only real problem in my case is freaking apostrophe (').

**Situation:** expanding `PATH` variable influence word completion, based on whether was apostrophes in additional path or not.

**Example:** I have an executable file (called `deadbeef`) with appropriate executable rights, the path to which contains 2 apostrophes:
`/home/mallniya/hard'n'soft/soft/gnu-linux/portable/deadbeef-0.6.0`
Specialy for an experiment I put the same file into to another directory:
`/home/mallniya/hardnsoftaa/soft/gnu-linux/portable/deadbeef-0.6.0`
If I export first path to the variable `PATH` there will be no autocompletion in `bash`, but there will be in the second case. When I type in terminal first letters of program in exported directory
`dead[TAB]`
There is no completion in first case, but when I use TAB with the same word in second condition - it works.
But if I type command `deadbeef` in first case manually - it also executes.

Moreover, both `which`and `type` commands tell, that the executable file is exists in both cases.

So what's the problem?

*note:*
I heard about links, using names without special symbols and other solutions for get thing simply working - I have no interest in it and just wonder: if I really have to use special symbol like this in PATH variable in the future, what could I do, to make autocompletion work? Is it a bug? And if yes - what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Now the real challenge for all of us is to find those 2 apostrophe in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a long-standing bug in bash. See [this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-10/msg00059.html) on the `bug-bash` mailing list. (As indicated in the thread, the bug was reported in 2008 as a problem with bash-completion scripts, but it is actually a problem in bash itself.)

Comment: Well, as bash_completion team advised, I have reported this behaviour and bash team answer is: "Thanks for the report.  This will be fixed in bash-4.3." looks like the bug is already known and we should just wait.

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophes are special characters to the shell used to tell `bash` to (amongst other things) not parse special characters such as `$`, `!`, or `\`.  If you have a directory with a `'` in its name, and you want it to be in your `PATH`, you need to escape them with backslashes, e. g. `.../hard\'n\'soft/...`.

It is for reasons like this that it is strongly discommended to have spaces, quotes, or other special characters in your file or directory names.

Comment: Of course I know about \ before special symbols, but PATH variable sets fine, command to execute binary or script (even without working autocompletion) works, which, as I understand, is a signal, that it really found in PATH variable. Problem laying deeper than just set special symbol somewhere.

Comment: I would not be shocked to discover that `bash_completion` was not designed to handle the edge case of `'`s embedded into the `PATH`.  I would start there if you want to find the cause of the misbehavior.

Comment: Already have, that's what they said: "Seems that we (bash-completion) have nothing to do with this; plain vanilla bash behaves as described. See "BUG REPORTS" in the bash man page if you wish to report it against bash."